# Как устанавливать модули\библиотеки на хостинге где нету pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Всем привет, На арендованном хостинге не установлен pip3\easy_install
Как мне без них устанавливать библиотечки
Например [Grab](http://github.com/lorien/grab), пробовал скачать его и получилось у меня вот что:

../

./grab  - скаченный библиотека

./script.py -в нем

```
import grab
g = grab.Grab()
```

но библиотеку не находит

Comment: Установить pip?

Comment: m9_psy, pip не устанавливается, ну нету прав на установку системных программ

Comment: pip и не должен требовать прав суперпользователя при установке - его можно посадить в изолированный virtualenv контейнер, а не глобально. Отвечая на ваш вопрос - вы можете скачать колесо (wheel) вручную и просто распаковать его - в колесе уже все собрано, скомпилировано и часто остается только распаковать готовое.

Comment: virtualenv принести можно?

Comment: Если все таки есть pip, но не устанавливает, можно попробовать с ключом `--user`, т.е. `pip install --user grab` поставит в `~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` А может быть уже и вовсе установлен `>>> help('modules')`.

Comment: Тот же `easy_install` может поставить и без прав `wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/90/d5/7264530cd505b022a9f19ae5429d5b139d927175dc70f60bd4b4d95d7ec1/grab-0.6.38.tar.gz; tar -xzf grab-0.6.38.tar.gz; cd grab-0.6.38/; easy_install . --user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если есть доступ к консоли, попробуйте создать виртуальное окружение:

```
# создаём
virtualenv venv

# активируем — меняются переменные окружения,
# теперь используется python, находящийся в venv/bin/python
source venv/bin/activate

# работаем
pip install ...
```

Если `virtualenv` тоже недоступно, можно создать его у себя и перенести.

Перед запуском вашего кода нужно будет точно так же активировать virtualenv.

---

Вот видео доклада про [перенос нужного Python-окружения почти на что угодно](https://vk.com/video-96469126_456239072).

Answer (score 0):

Скачать архив с pypi, распаковать и запустить setup.py.

Comment: И будет Permission denied

Comment: Ваш ответ решает проблему? Если да, то аргументентируйте это.