# "Портативное" PHP или Python/Django web приложение

Tags: php, python, веб-программирование, django

Существует ли возможность сделать PHP или Python/Django приложение переносным т.е. скопировать на флешку и запустить на другом компьютере?
Все выглядеть должно примерно так:

- Само приложение написано на PHP или Python/Django, база данных SQLite
- Интерпретатор и библиотеки НЕ устанавливается отдельно, а тянутся вместе с приложением в архиве
- При клике на ярлык запуска приложения, запускается встроенный в Python или PHP http сервер(есть в версиях >= 5.4) на свободном порту (например: 127.0.0.1:8080)
- После запуска сервера, запускается web браузер и открывает главную страницу приложения на адресе и порте которые использует web сервер (например: http://127.0.0.1:8080/)

Получится что-то вроде десктопного приложения, но только работать будет в браузере )
Я понимаю что это полное извращение, но есть обстоятельства которые не позволяют сделать по другому (разве что пилить полноценное десктопное приложение, на которое нет времени и бюджета)

Comment: Сделать всё это можно, только легче сделать обычное десктопное приложение.
Десктопные приложения вообще-то намного проще клиент-серверных.

Comment: Может быть, можно создать на флешке виртуальное окружение со всеми зависимостями и запускать в нём. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/666539/181472

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Python версия.**

Два варианта, первый сделать самому, второе взять готовое но чуть более старое например, http://portablepython.com/.

Про первый вариант подробнее.

Python не тянет особых зависимостей, поэтому устанавливаем (берем со своего компьютера) python, полностью всю папку и закидываем на флешку.

Далее в эту же папку ставим все модули и зависимые пакеты, в том числе и наше приложение на django.

Пишем простой бат файл, который переходит в папку питона и запускает наш проект, примерно вот так

```
cd python27
cd myproject
usr\bin\python27.exe manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8123
```

Проверка занятых портов и прочее ложиться на уровень запускающего файла.

**PHP версия.**
Аналогично питону можно самому собрать нужное, можно взять готовый portable пакет, например http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/download.php
Там все еще проще, в папку копируется сайт, сам сервер при необходимости запускается из папки. Значки запуска у большинства есть готовые.

Answer (score 1):

Если это будет **Python** то попробуй скомпилировать его с помощью **cx_freeze** или **py2exe** или же задействуй **Cython** и потом откомпилируй с помощью **gcc**. Все модули будут в одном exe файле, только вес будет очень большим. Но других вариантов я не знаю.